# Web page navigation

Tags: spring-mvc, navigation

I'm looking for guidelines for how to best implement web page navigation logic for a Spring based web application.  For example: I have a web page 'C' where if I click ok, I want flow to return to page 'A' if that was the previous page, or page 'B' if that was the previous page.  I am currently using hidden fields on a page to track from which page I arrived...but I think there must be a better way...

Comment: does the referrer header work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flash scope bean for saving the view Url from which you are redirected.

You can read about flash scope from this page:

http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/

See me response from this post. it Explains how to implement Flash Scope in SPring MVC environment.

[Spring MVC custom scope bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863472/spring-mvc-custom-scope-bean/5883270#5883270)

with this scope you can alway retrieve the URL form which you will redirected and then build link form the value retrieved.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use Spring Web Flow (http://www.springsource.org/webflow).

It's intended to do exactly what you want. Control the flows between pages.

I start using it a couple of month ago and I love it.