# Page Navigation with MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently looking for a good way to implement navigation between pages (without using any kind of dialogs) - particularly where a page is shared by more than one other page.

**Example**

There are three pages:

- ProductEdit
- OrderListItem
- ProductList

The ProductEdit page can be navigated to from both the OrderItemList and the ProductList pages.

The ProductEdit page has a cancel and an update action for it.  When the user clicks one of these actions I need control to return back to the page it came from.

**Multiple Levels**

Any ideas on the best way to implement this.  I also need to support this working at more than one level.

**Related Posting**
This is all MVC3 related but is very similar to another StackOverflow posting: [Web page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925732/web-page-navigation)

Many Thanks!

Comment: Are you fimilar with the ASP.Net-MVC structure? What is the problem **exactly**?

Comment: Fairly familiar with MVC. How would I know where to return back to when arriving on the ProductEdit page?  I'm familiar with the url referrer but this approach wouldn't work in multi-level senarios so I think that's UrlReferrer is out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProductEdit Page as partial view , and then check the `ViewBag.Title` to know in which page it came from. For example:

In OrderListItem Page :

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "OrderListItem";}
@Html.Partial("ProductEdit");
```

and same in ProductList Page. 
In ProductEdit Page check :

```
If ( ViewBag.Title = "OrderListItem")
```

//send value to your control with the title as paramter...

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I see what you are saying but this would tightly couple the ProductEdit page to all the other pages that request it.  I should point out that I wish the ProductEdit page to be a separate page (i.e. not a Partial).  Perhaps, prior to loading up the ProductEdit page I could store (either ViewBag or Model) the return action, controller and route data).  Could this work?

Comment: I don't really understand you. Why can't you implement @Html.Partial("ProductEdit") only in the Required pages?

Comment: Because I want to show the ProductEdit view in a separate page.  My understanding of Html.Partial is that it will render html in the containing view - this isn't something that I want to do - I wish to keep the ProductEdit view as a separate page that the user can navigate to.  I hope this makes it clear - sorry for any confusion.