# How to have flash scope functionality in Spring 3.0?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have ControllerA which performs quite a heavy duty logic and displays the result in html, the same set of result is now need to be exported in a excel sheet. I don't this is done by heavy duty stuff in controllerB again to generate and put it in excel.

Spring 3.1 have introduced Flash scope, like spring web flow but I don't think Spring 3.0 have such thing. 
Considering I cannot migrate to Spring 3.1 just as of now, I'm just wondering what would be the best and simplest thing I can do to get the same effect.
Should i go with some Custom scope?

Answer (score 2):

You don'h have it in 3.0, it's fully implemented only 3.1 and called `RedirectAttributes` this article covers it.
http://goo.gl/Qbym2

However there is a work around which I described in the post and it can help you if you can't upgrade to 3.1.

[Spring MVC custom scope bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863472/spring-mvc-custom-scope-bean/5883270#5883270)

Answer (score 1):

This might be of use - it shows how to implement flash scope in Java using a filter:

http://blog.smartkey.co.uk/2011/01/implementing-flash-scope-in-java-web-applications/