# RediectAttributes not working with spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, response.redirect

I am using spring security in my application.

In one of my controller method I am redirecting to another controller method and attaching model Attributes but I am not getting those modelAttributes in next controller method.

Is it happening because of some internal redirection from Spring Security Filter which might be killing those redirect flash attributes?

This is my code :

```
@RequestMapping("/method1")
public String firstMethod(Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  ... do something ...
  redirectAttributes.addFlashAttributes("message","This is a test message");
  return "redirect:/method2";
}

@RequestMapping("/method2")
public String secondMethod(@ModelAttribute("message") String message, Model model) {
  ... do something ...

  return "some_view";
}
```

Here in secondMethod message is coming as blank( "" );

Comment: try using `model.addAttribute()` Instead

Comment: model.addAttribute won't survive redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addAttribute` instead of `addFlashAttributes`

Read the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470111/spring-redirectattributes-addattribute-vs-addflashattribute)

```
@RequestMapping("/method1")
public String firstMethod(Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message","This is a test message");
  return "redirect:/method2";
}

@RequestMapping("/method2")
public String secondMethod(@ModelAttribute("message") String message, Model model) {
  return "some_view";
}
```

Comment: do you no why addFlashAttribute does not work when spring security is used?

Answer (score 0):

If you use redirect it wont carry headers or attribites.But You can maintain the session and you can use it if it's in same application.Using redirect means creating new request.

You better use Custom falsh scope

Comment: You're right. But that's why from Spring 3.1 onwards they have added RedirectAttributes which allows redirec requests to carry model Attributes. This doesn't seem to be working in my case because I think some of Spring Security filter is redirecting request but without adding flash Attributes from previous request.

Comment: Check this link you can find your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863472/spring-mvc-custom-scope-bean/5883270#5883270